# Using ThreadPoolExecutor under multiprocessing leads to deadlock in python2

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to submit functions in processes, and in each process it submit functions to a global threadPool.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
  
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=200)    
def fake_func():  
    time.sleep(3)
    print("??")


def query():
    print("submitted fake func threadpool: {}".format(executor))
    result = executor.submit(fake_func)
    result.result()
    print("Done fake func: {}".format(result.done()))
    return []


def simple_parallel(f, args_list):
    import multiprocessing as mp
    processes = []
    print("start")
    for args in args_list:
        p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(args))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join(timeout=10)
    return [None] * len(args_list)
```

The function runs fine with the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = []
    for result in simple_parallel(query, [()] * 10):
        if result:
            data.append(result)
```

However, if I submit a function to the threadpool before start the parallel call, it will hang forever.

```
result = executor.submit(fake_func)
result.result()
print("done dry call")

data = []
for result in simple_parallel(query, [()] * 10):
    if result:
        data.append(result)
```

I think the reason is that the subprocess will copy over the threadpool, and if there is already thread objects in the pool, they will be copied over too. However, threads are not copied over (thread itself). So when the subprocess's threadpool tried to reuse the thread, it cannot be found.

1. Is the statement correct?
2. Any suggestions on how to bypass it? This is a legacy code so I cannot easily avoid multiprocess.

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered a similar issue in python3 (but in multiprocessing module instead of thread module), and cython code callstack points to a deadlock along buffered I/O during `print`. So turning off the buffered IO solves the issue!